# Does speech recognition work for WAV files created with iOS devices?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, wav, avaudiorecorder, azure-cognitive-services

I have been trying to use the **`Microsoft SpeechSDK Speech Recognition`** backend to work with **`WAV`** files created using **`AVAudioRecorder`** and noticed that the **`DataRecognitionClient`** doesn't seem to return any errors or partial/final responses.

If however, I export that same `WAV` file using `Audacity` to **`WAV (Microsoft) signed 16 bit PCM`** it works fine.

**Repro**:

1. Using an Apple device use the AVAudioRecorder to create an audio.wav file (with less than 2 min of conversation) with the following format settings:

   ```
       let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
           AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatLinearPCM)),
           AVNumberOfChannelsKey: NSNumber(int: 1),
           AVSampleRateKey: NSNumber(float: 16000.0),
           AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: NSNumber(int: 16),
           AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
           AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false]
   ```
2. Download and open your https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-speech-stt-ios example project.
3. Open the SpeechRecognitionServerExample project and add the previously recorded audio.wav file (in step 1) into the SpeechRecognitionServerExample/Assets group.
4. Open ViewController.mm and go to the longWaveFile function and replace the file name with @"audio.wav"
5. Run the example and notice how no error is returned and nothing is recognized either.

**Analysis**:

The only thing that seems to be different from the provided sample WAV files in the project (batman.wav and whatstheweatherlike.wav) from the `SpeechSDK` samples is that the `WAV` files created by the `AVAudioRecorder` add the "FLLR" sub-chunk used for page alignment between the "fmt" and "data" sub-chunks in the file format header.

[RIFF WAV Apple vs Microsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP4M4.png)

While this is non-standard it still is specification compliant and it seems it might not be accounted for, preventing speech recognition from occurring. Are there any suggested work arounds for this?

**Update**:

So I went ahead and created a new audio recording class which uses `Audio Queues` and does exactly the same thing as `AVAudioRecorder`, except that it removes the "FLLR" sub-chunk. This can be done upon the creation of the audio file by setting the `AudioFileFlags.DontPageAlignAudioData` flag.

```
   AudioFileCreateWithURL(
            filePathUrl,
            kAudioFileWAVEType,
            &dataFormat,
            [.DontPageAlignAudioData, .EraseFile],
            &audioFile)
```

Doing this causes speech recognition to start working. Does anyone know if there is a way to indicate `AVAudioRecorder` to not page align the audio data? I read through the Apple documentation and couldn't find any setting or option. I really don't want to maintain something that duplicates the existing functionality just because of this.

Comment: You know there's a [built-in speech recognition service](https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech) in iOS 10, right?